# Simple Binary Adder

Tags: c++, homework, bitwise

The program adds two binary numbers in two' s complement ignoring the overflow for a constant size of bits. I am trying to generalize the program by taking input from the user in a single line without memory wastage. Is there any way to achieve this?

```
#include<iostream.h>
#include<conio.h>
void main ()
{

    const int size=9;
    enum bool {a=0, b=1};
    bool  carry,dummy;
    bool array[size]={0,0,1,1,1,1,1,0,1};
    bool reg[size]=  {1,0,1,1,1,0,1,0,1};

    for (int i=(size-1); i>=0 ; i--)
      {

         dummy=reg[i];
         reg[i]= (!reg[i]) && (array[i] !=carry) || reg[i] && (array[i]==carry);
         carry=(array[i]&&dummy) || (dummy&&carry) || (array[i]&&carry);

      }

    for (int j=0 ; j<size ; j++)
     {
      cout<<reg[j];
     }

}
```

Comment: For size, use constexpr, rather than const.

Answer (score 4):

- Everything is in `main`. You need to make `binary_add` function, which only adds things. It may even return interesting things (aka condition flags).
- `carry` is not initialized.
- I don't see how do you use `enum bool`.
- I don't see why do you `#include <conio.h>`
- Be consistent with spaces. `carry` computation is very crowded. Make it

  ```
  (array[i] && dummy) || (dummy && carry) || (array[i] && carry)
  ```

Answer (score 3):

Rather than converting to what is basically an integer array, which uses 16 bits per element, you'll find it much easier and more memory efficient to use a `bitset<>`, which stores 1 bit per element.  With this you can cheat and convert the decimal addition to a bitset:

```
const size_t BIT_LENGTH = 9;

bitset<BIT_LENGTH> AddBinary(int numA, int numB)
{
    bitset<BIT_LENGTH> answer(numA + numB);
    return answer;
}
```

Or if you truly want bit manipulation something like this would work:

```
bitset<BIT_LENGTH> AddBinary(int numA, int numB)
{
    bitset<BIT_LENGTH> binaryA(numA);
    bitset<BIT_LENGTH> binaryB(numB);
    bitset<1> carry;
    for (int i = 0; i < BIT_LENGTH; i++)
    {
        bitset<2> temp(binaryA[i] + binaryB[i] + carry[0]);
        binaryA[i] = temp[0];
        carry[0] = temp[1];
    }
    return binaryA;
}
```

Now you can get the user to input integers and displaying the results is a simple matter of:

```
cout << AddBinary(numa,numb);
```